# Size of buffer to hold base58 encoded data

Tags: bitcoin, base58

When trying to understand how base58check works, in the [referenced implementation](https://github.com/bitcoin/libbase58/) by bitcoin, when calculating the size needed to hold a base58 encoded string, it used following formula:

```
// https://github.com/bitcoin/libbase58/blob/master/base58.c#L155
size = (binsz - zcount) * 138 / 100 + 1;
```

where `binsz` is the size of the input buffer to encode, and `zcount` is the number of leading zeros in the buffer. What is 138 and 100 coming from and why?

Comment: it means each 100 decoded character will become 138 encoded character or the other way

Comment: what's the theory behind that?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never studied bitcoin and philosophy behind choosing B58 encoding. my answer is based on B64 which is `* 4 / 3`. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) says `to avoid both non-alphanumeric characters and letters which might look ambiguous when printed` such as `0, o, O` and `I, l, 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr
It’s a formula to approximate the output size during `base58 <-> base256` conversion.
i.e. the encoding/decoding parts where you’re multiplying and mod’ing by 256 and 58

Encoding output is `~138%` of the input size (+1/rounded up):

```
n * log(256) / log(58) + 1  
(n * 138 / 100 + 1)
```

Decoding output is `~73%` of the input size (+1/rounded up):

```
n * log(58) / log(256) + 1  
( n * 733 /1000 + 1)
```

Comment: decoding output is usually 73% of input size. But you could also have an input that is almost all leading zeros, in which case the decoded would be ~100% of input size (each leading "1" character decodes into a single zero byte).